# How can I track the mouse pointer when it is outside of the widget that is tracking it using PyQt4?

Tags: python-3.x, mouseevent, pyqt4

I have a QWidget (with mouse tracking enabled) that does not occupy my whole computer screen. I want to know the mouse pointer global position every time it moves, even if it moves out of the QWidget. So far I can manage to do this only inside the widget (by overriding `mouseMoveEvent` in the widget code). How can I track the pointer when it is outside of the widget?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19231037/625350) seems to indicate that it's not possible using only Qt.

Comment: @titusjan thank you for your useful comment.